# MySql Query issue regarding get several rows related to one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table like below in my MySql database.

table_books

```
book_author         book_name                       book_page   book_price  book_published_date book_topic

James Anderson      Introduction to PHP             200         50          1/12/2013           Science
James Anderson      Expert in jQuery                150         40          8/7/2014            Programming
James Anderson      HTML                            200         60          5/9/2012            Web
Richard Benjamin    Successful stories of Business  300         70          4/6/2014            Business
Richard Benjamin    Entrepreneurship                500         80          8/9/2013            Business
Richard Benjamin    Business Studies                100         40          2/5/2012            Business
```

I would like to get result like below

```
book_author James Anderson              

book_name           book_page   book_price  book_published_date book_topic  

Introduction to PHP 200         50          1/12/2013           Science 
Expert in jQuery    150         40          8/7/2014            Programming 
HTML                200         60          5/9/2012            Web 




book_author Richard Benjamin                


book_name                       book_page   book_price  book_published_date book_topic  

Successful stories of Business  300         70          4/6/2014            Business    
Entrepreneurship                500         80          8/9/2013            Business    
Business Studies                100         40          2/5/2012            Business
```

I need the SQL Query. I need to pick up one row(book_author) with other associate rows.

Thanks

Comment: Showing reports is done on the client side. There's no SQL query for this, at least no simple one you would like to do in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sqlAuthor = "SELECT DISTINCT book_author FROM book_name";
    $exeAuthor = mysql_query($sqlAuthor);
    if($exeAuthor)
    {
        while($dataAuthor = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeAuthor))
        {
            $sqlBookRec = "SELECT * FROM book_name where book_author='".$dataAuthor['book_author']."'";
            $exeBookRec = mysql_query($sqlBookRec);
            if($exeBookRec)
            {
                echo "Book Author: ".$dataAuthor['book_author'];
                while($dataBookRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeBookRec))
                {
                    echo "Book Name".$dataBookRec['book_name'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Try this. Hopefully, it'll work.

Comment: Thanks @Mike DaVinci. But I would like to retrieve whole record using one  Query. Thanks

Comment: It cannot be done with one query. Similar to my original post (which I've deleted) you must do a query for each author if you want to return them separately.

Comment: @Juliousceazer: I'm not a PHP guy, so I can't write the code, but you simply run a SELECT without any WHERE-condition and `ORDER BY book_author`.  Then you apply cursor logic inside the WHILE-fetch: Remember the current row's `book_author`, fetch the next row, when the name changed echo the author. Plus one line for each book.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for your reply. May be only you got my point. I would like to know more about cursor logic. Could you help me with some website link from where I could get solution?? Thanks

Comment: @Juliousceazer: Cursor logic is considered bad practice in SQL, because it's row-by-row-processing and SQL is made for processing sets of data. That's why should you do the format/report in the front-end using PHP. Plus SQL simply can't return results sets with different record layouts.

Comment: I could not understand your words. Thanks